# In Haskell, why does `True || True && False` return True

Tags: haskell

I tested `(True || True) && False` and it returns `False` as expected as `True or True` will become `True`, which is then put into `True and False` which returns `False`.
Shouldn't it work even without the parantheses, doesn't the code work its way from left to right ?

To see if the right side is completely ignored after the second `True`. I also tested `True || True && 8` just as a random non boolean placeholder and it gave an error.

Comment: Code isn't evaluated from left to right. Operators have precedence, just like in `1 + 2 * 3` the multiplication is done first.

Comment: When I was first taught Boolean many years ago, our symbols were 0 (false), 1 (true), + (or), * (and), and it was exactly like regular arithmetic but with the special rule 1 + 1 = 1. And just like it usually is, `(1 + 1) * 0 = 0`, while `1 + 1 * 0 = 1`.

Answer (score 9):

**tl;dr** summary: For the same reason that `2 + 3 * 4` is `24` instead of `20`, which it should be by your argument (code being evaluated left-to-right).

[The precedence of `&&` is 3 whereas the precedence of `||` is 2](https://haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#fixity).

Therefore, `&&` binds tighter than `||`, or, in other words, `True || True && False` is the same as `True || (True && False)`.

According to [the definition of `||`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.10.0/docs/src/GHC.Classes.html#%7C%7C):

```haskell
True  || _ = True
False || x = x
```

So, it is irrelevant what comes to the right of `True ||`, the result will always be `True`. In fact, the right argument isn't even evaluated, so even if you had something which causes an infinite loop or an exception on the right-hand side of `True ||`, the result would still be `True`.

Note that this is not specific to Haskell. Pretty much every programming language which has a concept of *precedence* has logical-AND bind tighter than logical-OR. It isn't even specific to programming, the same is true in mathematical logic: `∧` binds tighter than `∨` in Boolean Algebra, for example.

In fact, this is even more general: in ℤ<sub>|2</sub>, i.e. the integers modulo 2, `×` is the same as `∧` and `+` is the same as `⊻` (XOR):

| `×` | `0` | `1` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `0` | `0` | `0` |
| `1` | `0` | `1` |

| `∧` | `0` | `1` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `0` | `0` | `0` |
| `1` | `0` | `1` |

| `+` | `0` | `1` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `0` | `0` | `1` |
| `1` | `1` | `0` |

| `⊻` | `0` | `1` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `0` | `0` | `1` |
| `1` | `1` | `0` |

| `∨` | `0` | `1` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `0` | `0` | `1` |
| `1` | `1` | `1` |

So, these precedence rules are actually just instances of more general examples like the fact that `×` binds tighter than `+` in standard arithmetic.